# Special sectioning requirements

Tags: sectioning, fontsize

I'm writing a book chapter and the editor has some specific formatting requirements.  In particular, he wants the section titles to be centered and not bold.  I'm using `titlesec` with:

```
\titleformat{\section}
  {\normalfont\fontfamily{cm}\fontsize{16}{19}\selectfont}{\thesection}{1em}{}
```

This ensures the section title is not bold.  To make it centered, I did:

```
\titleformat{\section}
  \centering{{\normalfont\fontfamily{cm}\fontsize{16}{19}\selectfont}{\thesection}}{1em}{}
```

However, this somehow ignores the fontsize, resulting in a unbolded, centered, but small font sized section title.  How can I ensure the fontsize is larger, as indicated in the command?

Comment: The syntax in the second code is wrong, as `\centering` should go *after* the opening brace and not before; also `cmr` is the family name, but you don't need it.

Answer (score 3):

Your syntax is wrong; here is a more correct one. The arguments to `\titleformat` needn't be specified in this format, but this I find it more readable to keep each one in a separate line.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\titleformat{\section}
 {\centering\normalfont\fontsize{16}{19}\selectfont}
 {\thesection}
 {1em}
 {}

\begin{document}
\chapter{First}
\section{A title}
\end{document}
```

I added `\usepackage{lmodern}` in order to have arbitrarily scalable fonts. Note that giving `\fontfamily` is redundant, because `\normalfont` already sets the default font family.

[image]